# how do I remove the white space on the right side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When viewed on mobile, a white space appears on the right side of my site.

This is what I have done.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>BUDWEISER</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/zoombox.css" media="screen">
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.7.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body role="document">


    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=956935597733326";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


        <div class="container-fluid" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="header" style="background: #c41a30;"> <!-- the top red section -->
                    <div class="logo-small">
                            <img src="images/drink-responsibly.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="logo-small-retina">
                            <img src="images/low-res/drink-responsibly-retina.png" id="top-right-retina">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="main-logo">
                        <img src="images/budweiser.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-logo-retina">
                        <img src="images/low-res/budweiser-retina.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="dream-header">
                        <img src="images/dream-header.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="dream-header-retina">
                        <img src="images/low-res/dream-header-retina.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="map">
                        <div class="ireland">
                            <img src="images/ireland-map.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="rollOver">
                            <img src="images/spacercircle.png">
                            <div class="sandra">
                                <a class="zoombox zgallery1" w250 h250 title="Dream Big" href="video/dream-job.mp4">
                                    <img src="images/sandra-icon.png"  alt="dream job video" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="map-retina">
                        <div class="ireland-retina">
                            <img src="images/low-res/ireland-map-retina.png">
                        </div>  
                        <div class="rollOver">
                            <img src="images/spacercircle.png">
                            <div class="sandra">
                                <a class="zoombox zgallery1" w250 h250 title="Dream Big" href="video/dream-job.mp4">
                                    <img src="images/sandra-icon.png"  alt="dream job video" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>      
                    <div class="text-map">
                        <img src="images/text-below-map.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-map-retina">
                        <img src="images/low-res/text-below-map-retina.png">
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="iradio">
                <div class="iradio-logo">
                        <img src="images/iradio-logo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="iradio-logo-retina">
                        <img src="images/low-res/iradio-logo-retina.png">
                </div>
                <div class="garry-text">
                        <img src="images/garry.png">
                </div>
                <div class="garry-text-retina">
                        <img src="images/low-res/garry-retina.png">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="garry">
                <div class="garrybg">
                        <div class="centerVideo">
                        <video id="garry-vid" class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" style="width:100%; height:auto;"
                                   data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
                                    <source src="video/dream-job.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
                                    <p class="vjs-no-js">
                                      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                                      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                                    </p>
                          </video>
                        </div>
                </div>
<!--                <div class="garrybg-retina">
                        <video id="garry-vid-retina" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="120" height="78"
                                   data-setup=" {fluid: true}">
                                    <source src="video/dream-job.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
                                    <p class="vjs-no-js">
                                      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                                      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                                    </p>
                        </video>
                        <img src="images/low-res/garry-bg-retina.png">
                </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="enter">
                <div class="enter-text">
                    <img src="images/enter.png">    
                </div>  
                <div class="enter-text-retina">
                    <img src="images/low-res/enter-retina.png">
                </div>  
            </div>  

            <div class="win" style="background: #c41a30;">
                <div class="chancetowin">
                    <img src="images/your-chance.png">  
                </div>  
                <div class="chancetowin-retina">
                    <img src="images/low-res/your-chance-retina.png">
                </div>  
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="btn-submit">
                    <form action="action_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" cols="150" id="comment" placeholder="SHARE YOUR DREAM!"></textarea>

                    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://localhost/projects/budweiser/" data-layout="button"></div>

                    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://localhost/projects/budweiser/" data-text="Check this Out" data-hashtags="DreamBig">Tweet</a>
                    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
                    </script>

                    <input type="image" src="images/submit-button.png" id="btn">
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="social" style="background: #c41a30;">
                <img src="images/dream-social.png" id="share">
            </div>
            <div class="social-retina" style="background: #c41a30;">
                <img src="images/low-res/dream-social-retina.png">
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/156422073" class="footer-vid" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

                <!-- <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/156422073" class="footer-vid-retina" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> -->

            </div>
            </div>

        </div>  


                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
                <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script><!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
                <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.7.1/video.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/zoombox.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function() {
                $('a.zoombox').zoombox();
              });
                </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.row{

    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}



.container-fluid{
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
   }
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;

}
        .logo-small img{ 
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 30%;
            height: 10%;
            padding-top: 30px;
            margin-left: 60px;
        }


        .logo-small-retina {
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: none;
        }

        .main-logo{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }

        .main-logo img{
            width: 15%;
            height: 10%;

        }
        .main-logo-retina{

            display: none;
        }

        .dream-header{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-left: -40px;
        }

        .dream-header img{
            width: 40%;
            height: 10%;
        }

        .dream-header-retina{
            display: none;
        }

        .map{

            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .map-retina{
            display: none;
        }

        .ireland{

            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 65px;
        }

        .ireland img {
            position: relative;
            width: 40%;
            height: 10%;
            margin-top: -4%;
        }

        .ireland-retina{

            display: none;
        }


        .sandra img {
        /*display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 105px;
        margin-top: -50%;
        margin-left: 14%;*/
    }
        .rollOver {
            display: block;
            width: 2%;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 47.69%;
            margin-top: -22.5%;
        }
        .sandra{
            display: none; 
            position: relative;
            width: 250%;
            margin-top: -790%;
            margin-left: -176%;
}
        }


        .sandra img {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;

        }




        .text-map{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20%;
            margin-bottom: 5%;
        }

        .text-map img {
            position: relative;
            width: 40%;
            height: 10%;
            display: block;
            margin-top: 24%;
            margin-left: 27%;
            margin-right: 27%;
        }

        .text-map-retina{

            display: none;
        }

.iradio{

    margin-top: 20px;
}
        .iradio-logo{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;

        }
        .iradio-logo-retina{

            display: none;
        }

        .iradio-logo img{
            width: 10%;
            height: 5%; 
        }

        .garry-text{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;

        }

        .garry-text img{
            width: 20%;
            height: 10%;    
        }
        .garry-text-retina{

            display: none;
        }
.garry{
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top: 20px;*/
}

        .garrybg{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            background: url("../images/garry-bg.png") no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            text-align: center;

        }
        .centerVideo {
            margin: auto;
            width:33%;
        }
        .garrybg-retina{
            display: none;
        }




.enter{
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top: 20px;*/
}       
        .enter-text{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;


        }

        .enter-text img{
            width: 10%;
            height: 5%;
            mar
        }

        .enter-text-retina{
            display: none;
        }
.win{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    /*margin-top: 20px;*/
}       
        .chancetowin{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;


        }

        .chancetowin img{
            width: 70%;
            height: 55%;
            mar
        }

        .chancetowin-retina{
            display: none;
        }

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.social-retina{
        display: none;
}

.form-control{

    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn-submit{
        width: 75%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 25px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        display: block;
}

#btn {
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#share{

    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    height: 10%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px; 
}

.player .title{

    display: none;
}

.fb-share-button{
    margin: 4px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.twitter-share-button{
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.footer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer-vid{
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}

.footer-vid-retina{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){

        .container-fluid{
            width: 100%;
        }

        .row{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .header{
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }

        .logo-small{
            display: none;
        }

        .logo-small-retina{
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            padding-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        .main-logo{
            display: none;
        }

        .main-logo-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .main-logo-retina img{
            position: relative;
            width: 150px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-left: 105px;
            margin-right: 105px;
        }

        .dream-header{
            display: none;
        }

        .dream-header-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .dream-header-retina img {
            position: relative;
            width: 318px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-left: 7px;
            margin-right: 7px;
        }

        .map{
            display: none;
        }

        .map-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .ireland{
            display: none;
        }

        .ireland-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .ireland-retina img {
            position: relative;
            width: 318px;
            margin-top: -5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-left: 7px;
            margin-right: 7px;
        }

        .text-map{
            display: none;
        }

        .text-map-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .text-map-retina img {
            position: relative;
            width: 318px;
            margin-top: 35px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-left: 7px;
            margin-right: 7px;
        }

        .iradio{
            width: 330px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .iradio-logo{
            display: none;
        }

        .iradio-logo-retina{
            display:block;
        }

        .iradio-logo-retina img {
        position: relative;
        width: 40%;
        margin-top: -12px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 93px;
        margin-right: 69px;
        }

        .garry-text{
            display: none;
        }

        .garry-text-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .garry-text-retina img {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: -31px;
        margin-left: 69px;
        margin-right: 69px;
        }

        .garrybg{
            background: none;
        }

        .centerVideo{
            width: 100%;

        }

    /*  .garrybg-retina{
            display: block; 
            height: 40px;
        }

        .garrybg-retina img {
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
        margin-top: -246px;
        margin-bottom: -240px;
        margin-left: -23px;
        margin-right: 69px;
        }*/


        #garry-vid-retina{
            margin-left: 117px;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: -48px;
        }

        .enter-text{
            display: none;
        }

        .enter-text-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .enter-text-retina img {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: -136px;
        margin-bottom: -138px;
        margin-left: 65px;
        margin-right: 65px;
        }

        .win {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80%;
        margin-top: 44px;
        padding-top: 50px;
        /* margin-top: 20px; */
        }

        .chancetowin{
            display: none;
        }

        .chancetowin-retina{
            display: block;
        }

        .chancetowin-retina img{
            position: relative;
            width: 340px;
            margin-top: -35px;
            margin-left: 6px;
            margin-right: 6px;
        }


        .social{
            display: none;
        }
        .social-retina{
            display:block;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .footer-vid{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            height: 242px;
        }
    }
```

How do I resolve this.

I have integrated bootstrap 3.3.6

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Hi. As far as I concern the default value for the "margin-left" & "margin-right" for the "row" class in bootstrap is "-15px".

I can't help you much because I need full view of your codes.

Comment: It's probably an element who wider than the content. Do you have a public URL so we could dive into it?

Comment: @sandalkoyak thanks for replying. I have pasted all my code above. 

and the margin right and left are 0px.

Comment: @MoshFeu ohk. as far as I can, all of them are of the size. 

no, I dont. the site is not live yet. its only on my localhost

Comment: apply css style margin:0px for body tag and check

Comment: I checked you markup and css in my browser.Its working fine form me.

Comment: @PavanTeja if you go in developer tools, and choose the mobile view. 

and then slide the site to left, you will see the white space.

Comment: That is a lot of CSS...I placed your code into a JSFiddle and do not see the white space when I shrink it to mobile size. Unless it is an image causing the issue (they don't load because you have local images), then it is brutal to try to debug all of that. Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/fncf89ky/

Comment: guys, I have resolved the isse. 

I added, overflow: hidden property to my row-fluid class in media queries and it worked. thanks again all

Comment: you never used row-fluid.. but you deleted the minus-margin from the rows, which should actually avoid mistakes like this, cause it subtracts the given padding from the container.